# Jenkins: Copy artifacts from Windows master to OSX slave - incorrect directory structure

Tags: macos, jenkins

We're currently using the Copy Artifact Plugin for Jenkins (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) and we're doing it in a way that the project from our Windows master machine will copy it's artifacts to a osx slave machine.

The problem is that the folder structure is broken when it's being copied to the slave machine, since Windows uses "\" character in its directory while OSX uses "/".

When it's being copied to the slave machine, it just creates a single folder with this file name:

> c/\Jenkins\workspace\foldername

Wherein it should create 3 folders: Jenkins, workspace, and foldername; each folder inside the next item like so:

> Jenkins>workspace>foldername

Is there a way to restructure the directory upon copying the artifacts? Or is there any other plugin we can use to fix this?

Comment: what are the options your are selecting in `copy artifacts` plugin?

Comment: I only fill up the project name, i set it to get the latest successful build, and the path for the artifacts to copy. I don't see any options to change the format of the path before it does the copy. is there an option for that?